# Is google-cloud-storage pricing dependent on the bucket location?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

i have dedicated server in `canada` and would like to use `google-cloud-storage` as offsite backup.

so i will be pushing/uploading data from `canada` to `google-cloud-storage` located in `us-east1`.

will there be any pricing difference if i create a bucket in `us-central1` instead of `us-east1` ?

**or the pricing is same for any location ?**

i ask this becuase i have been using amazon services and their pricing totally depends on the location of amazon server/services .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Google Cloud Storage charges the same amount for storing data regardless of the location it's stored, and there is no charge for uploading data into Google Cloud Storage.

There are some pricing differences for serving data based on location, but for serving data from Google to outside of Google, us-centra1 and us-east1 are effectively equivalent in this regard.

The pricing details for Google Cloud Storage are published here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Comment: thanks for clarification, i have seen already seen the storage pricing page, but couldnt find what i was looking for., thanks again.